# Why Don't Protestants Cross Themselves?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, sign-of-the-cross

Most Protestants (excluding a majority of Lutherans and Anglicans), don't cross themselves. What is the basis behind this?

Comment: Probably for the same reasons their pastors don't wear vestments. IOW, high church vs. low church.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering what the reasoning is behind this practice (or lack of a practice I guess)

Comment: Why should they? It's neither commanded nor even described in the Bible. Shouldn't the question be directed to those who do practice this gesture?

Comment: @curiousdannii Well considering it was common practice among the original two Churches (EO's and Catholics), it seems odd that the practice would just end for no reason.

Comment: It's not odd at all. The whole point of the reformation was to cast off things with no connection to the scriptures.

Comment: @curiousdannii Right but the Lutherans and the Anglicans still practice it. Why didn't they reject it?

Comment: It's not *opposed* by the scriptures, so there's nothing wrong with it in general. And the Lutherans were the first Protestant branch and so naturally are closer to Catholicism. From reading Wikipedia it sounds like it was reintroduced into Anglicanism by some anglo-catholics later on

Comment: @curiousdannii "_Why should they?_" Because [early Christians did](https://librivox.org/the-sign-of-the-cross-in-the-nineteenth-century-by-jean-joseph-gaume/).

Comment: @Geremia Tertullian said “In all our travels and movements, in all our coming in and going out, in putting on our shoes, at the bath, at the table, in lighting our candles, in lying down, in sitting down, whatever employment occupies us, we mark our foreheads with the sign of the cross”.  Should we all do it this often because early Christians did?

Comment: @MikeBorden yes

Comment: @jaredad7 I honestly knew a man who decided that he would say "Thank you, Lord!" out loud at every single event.  The car started ... "Thank you, Lord!",  the refrigerator works ... "Thank you, Lord!", I can taste my food ... "Thank you, Lord".   It didn't last because he was literally, constantly saying "Thank you, Lord!", and, at it's most fervent height, he found he could not say "Thank you, Lord!" at each inhale and exhale without crippling his life but the thankful attitude of his heart has won the day.  He need not say it constantly since he feels it constantly.  God sees the heart.

Comment: God sees the heart, to be sure. But the point of signing yourself frequently is to remind yourself that you are a baptized child of God.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the reformers emphasis on sola scriptura, this particular practice is not found in Scripture and was seen as idolatry by some reformers. Because Protestantism is rooted in the reformation, there is a historically rooted hesitancy to explore practices not found directly in the Scriptures. However, as with other traditions from throughout Christian history, there are Protestants today who are exploring the adoption of the sign of the cross (see second article). Certainly most Protestants would not feel that the sign of the cross had any special power, but perhaps they would adopt it as a reminder of what Christ has done for us.

https://catholicstraightanswers.com/what-is-the-origin-of-the-sign-of-the-cross/

https://baptistnews.com/article/a-case-for-making-the-sign-of-the-cross-even-for-us-baptists-and-other-protestants/

Comment: Sola scriptura does *not* refer to only doing things in the scriptures - that's the [regulative principle of worship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulative_principle_of_worship). Which is probably relevant to this question, but would only be an answer for some protestants, as many protestants reject the regulative principle.

Comment: I like this answer, but I almost want to ask a second question on why Luther kept it since its still tradition.

Comment: @LukeHill  From the wiki article: "On this basis, many early Calvinists also eschewed musical instruments and advocated exclusive psalmody in worship".  Now I see why JS Bach, a Lutheran, whose main output was sacred music wouldn't thrive if he were a Calvinist.  I think he might not even achieved this if he were Catholic; because of the restrictions in musical forms he could compose in.  Mozart was Catholic, relatively few sacred compositions.

Comment: [This recent journal article](https://digitalcommons.cedarville.edu/musicalofferings/vol10/iss2/3/) describes JS Bach's piety and understanding of theology and how his music was suffused with both.

Comment: @LukeHill Luther also accepted transubstantiation as far as I know. He was, after all, a Catholic monk who sought reformation, so it makes sense he would retain certain elements of his prior form of worship. Another possible explanation is that as time passed protestants slowly shed more and more of their Catholic heritage just because they were disconnected from that context. These types of questions don't generally have simple answers with a single right explanation - it's a combination of various social, political, and religious historical developments.

Answer (score 0):

It’s like why some Christians don't practice the laying on of hands when praying for others in a personalized manner. It’s why some Christians don’t hug when greeting people, when COVID is not a threat.  It’s why some people don’t like to say “amen” out loud in appreciation of a sermon. It’s why some churches discourage clapping after a beautiful song. It’s why some like to lift up their hands to worship God while others prefer to fold their hands. It’s mostly due to cultural differences.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question. People of the same culture in the reformation stopped this practice. I want to know the reasoning behind it. Culture doesn’t work.

Comment: I don't think it was ever taught by any of the Reformers that one should not make the sign of the cross. Martin Luther says in his Small Catechism: “In the morning and in the evening . . . you shall bless yourself with the sign of the holy cross and say, In the Name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit." Yet, very few Lutherans in America start their morning or end their evenings with that ritual.